# Changing android.os.build.serial

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms

In terms of using android.os.build serial as a unique identifier

1. How/when is it generated
2. When does it change
3. Is it possible to manually change the value back to something that I had before
4. Is it something that can be expected to be available across devices and operating systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most of these properties are in /system/build.prop (or a file like that). But i believe the `android.os.build.serial` is actually set when the device first boots. The system gets the device serial number and adds it to the properties.

I actually found a commit in some cyanogenmod code that you can see how exactly it is set:
(now this does say it is somewhat of a hack, but it is set when the device boots).

From [Git](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_device_bn_encore/commit/f6586ab41f0e3f5acfa16b43f9b17008e9bb0524):

```
57| sprintf(buf, "ro.serialno=%s", serial);
```

Comment: So can this value be easily changed (also considering that some users may be root)?

Comment: no, but i guess it could be changed with a custom ROM. if the custom ROM defines how the serial is retrieved from the device differently then how it is now.

Comment: I mean, given root privileges, can a user modify build.props or some other file (possibly modifying the sqlite database) to alter this value?

Comment: no, it comes from the hardware.

Comment: So if the number changed when I upgraded my rom (CM7 -> CM7.2) theres no easy way to change it back?

Comment: @arc Titanium Backup Pro supports backup and restore of this id.

Comment: any way to do it manually?

Comment: @RyanConrad, no I believe it does not come from the hardware, but it should behave as if it came from the hardware - it is supposed to be the equivalent of an IMEI/IMSI (which comes from a telephony device's hardware) for device's without telephony.